# Hide table if its <td> is empty (Using only JS)

Tags: javascript, html-table, hide, onload

I want to hide a table if its "td" empty.
I'm trying to use this function, but it's not working:

```
function isEmptyTable(){
    var tdTable = document.getElementsByName('tdTable').textContent;
    var table = document.getElementsByName('tableToday');
    if(tdTable == "")
        table.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Any tips?

HTML:

```
<body onload="isEmptyTable()">
                <table name="tableToday"> 
                    <thead>

                        <tr>
                            <th>Prêmio</th>
                            <th>Resultado</th>
                            <th>Grupo</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>1º</th>
                            <td name="tdTable">oi</td>
                            <td name="tdTable"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Could provide your html aswell? And when is your function called?

Comment: Ok, I update the question

Comment: You're getting multiple tds. As soon as one contains text none will be hidden. Try using an iteration.

Comment: all the td need to be empty to hide the table ?

Comment: Is your question solved? If so please mark the answer as such. If you found one yourself you may want to post it and mark that one as response.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `getElementById` and the `getElementsByClassName` selectors to achieve this:

```js
function isEmptyTable(myId){
    let tds = document.getElementsByClassName(myId);
    let hide = false
    for (let element of tds) {
      if (element.innerHTML.length == 0) hide = true
    }
    let myTable = document.getElementById(myId);
    if (hide) myTable.style.display = 'none';
}
isEmptyTable("myTable")
isEmptyTable("myTable2")
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="myTable"></td>
    <td class="myTable">
     lololo
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="myTable2">
  <tr>
    <td class="myTable2">asdasd</td>
    <td class="myTable2">
     lololo
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code just change these two lines. because the td will return in collection so use array index [0]

```
function isEmptyTable(){
var tdTable = document.getElementsByName('tdTable')[0].textContent;
var table = document.getElementsByName('tableToday')[0];
if(tdTable == "")
    table.style.display = 'none';
```

}

it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the part:

```
var tdTable = document.getElementsByName('tdTable').textContent;
```

and

```
table.style.display = 'none';
```

Because the function `document.getElementsByName()` doesn't return a simple variable , it's return an array , so to solve the problem you have to change the part:

```
var tdTable = document.getElementsByName('tdTable').textContent;
```

to

```
var tdTable = document.getElementsByName('tdTable')[0].textContent;
```

and change `table.style.display = 'none';` to `table[0].style.display = 'none';`

For more information about `document.getElementsByName()` [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

Comment: Actually, I have 9 tables with 8 rows in each one, how can I go through all of them without having to swap index by index?

Comment: You can use "for loop"